# How to replicate the CSRF vulnerability in Wordpress 4.0?

Tags: wordpress, csrf

I've been reading around and noticed that WordPress 4.0 has a CSRF vulnerability in the wp-login.php file (https://wpvulndb.com/vulnerabilities/7691). It allows users that make the authenticated user visit a HTML file change the password for the authenticated user. As I've been running WordPress 4.0 for a while myself, I have now upgraded it and put it on localhost to try and test this vulnerability as I wanted to see how hard it actually would be to get in.

Now I have struggled across two questions: There is always a key generated at the password reset, how is that even bypassed? Plus, wouldn't I receive an email to confirm the password change?

I've tried to 'exploit' or use this vulnerability to reset the password of my own account. I created a post form, but that didn't work - always getting "you must be authenticated" - no matter what I do.

Can someone direct me to the right direction? Or provide an example? That would be really appreciated, as I don't see a way to create that on my own. I just want this for testing purposes to know the impact and if it would work at all.

Comment: I'd hope that anyone with the skills to exploit this would also have the decency not to write a 'how to' on Stackoverflow about it.

Comment: @McNab: I have to disagree. You have to be able to understand attacks in order to defend against them (either as a vendor or as an organisation or individual using the software). Usually keeping the exploit private for a time period (like [Google's 90 day policy](http://www.welivesecurity.com/2015/01/05/google-reveals-windows-8-1-security-exploit-90-day-period-elapses/)) is a good idea to give the vendor some time to patch - but after that the exploit should be revealed so ethical hackers can properly test systems and networks. Also in this case it appears to be a standard CSRF.

Comment: @Doe: Have you logged into Wordpress before trying your cross site request? That's a requirement of CSRF attacks as the attack uses the authentication cookies of the logged in user automatically sent by the browser.

Comment: @SilverlightFox - I completely understand what you are saying.  However all the OP needs to do to defend against this is upgrade his Wordpress install.  He isn't a Wordpress core developer (or I'd be very surprised if he is!) so it's not him that needs to understand it and patch it.  Anybody explaining in detail here how someone with malicious intent could hack a site one minor version down from the latest version would most certainly not be doing the Wordpress community a favour.

Comment: @McNab: Yep agreed - the product developer needs time to patch things before they are made public. In this case it sounds like a simple CSRF so it wouldn't take an attacker long. I haven't investigated myself into this particular instance though.